# call the default constructor for the pointer of class as a value of map in c++

Tags: c++

Here is my class

```
struct Node 
{
    int val;
    vector<Node*> children;
    Node() :val(0), children({}){};
    Node(int _val) :val(_val) {};
};
```

And I build a `map`

```
map<int,Node*> dict;
```

I know that the pointer object will not call for the constructor of class, so if the key `i` does not exist in map, we are not allowed to use the code like:

```
dict[i]->val = i;
```

instead, we should do like

```
if (!dict.count(i)) 
{
    Node* node = new Node(i);
    dict[i] = node;
}
```

So is it possible to modify the definition of class to allowed us to do `dict[i]->val = i` for the nonexistent key.

Comment: Why are you storing `Node*`s in the map instead of just `Node`s, or failing that, `std::unique_ptr<Node>`s?  And the same question applies to `Node::children`; why is that using (raw) pointers?

Comment: @DanielH Sorry I am not familiar with the unique_ptr, so given a id ·i·, how do we call its corresponding unique_ptr?

Comment: So, with `std::unique_ptr`, `ptr` is short for “pointer”.  Itʼs like a regular pointer with `*`, but where you donʼt have to call `delete` explicitly (or `new`, if you use the `std::make_unique` function, which you should).  Itʼs good practice to use that instead of raw pointers, but in this case I donʼt know if you even need that or if you should just use `Node` directly instead of any sort of pointner.

Comment: If you use a `map` to order `dict` by `Node::val`, you may want to consider a `std::set<Node>` instead. You would add `bool operator<(Node,Node)` so `std::set<Node>` knows how to order your nodes.

Comment: Who owns those `Node` objects? Please explain how are they going to be **deleted**. That can make important difference to the answer. Also, will some other object (apart from the map element) store a pointer to `Node` in that map? If yes, then what should happen to that pointer once the map element is erased/destroyed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to make value initialised pointer to be a valid pointer to object, and that is what you will always get for objects created by `std::map::operator[]`. Such pointer is always null.

Instead of storing a pointer to node, you could store the node itself in the map element. The syntax of accessing the elements would be different, but you would achieve what you want otherwise:

```
map<int,Node> dict;
dict[i].val = i; // map now contains a node
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator[]` does insert an element when it finds none for the given key and it does not tell you if there was an element before. Note that it has quite different semantics from the "usual" `operator[]`. For example in a vector you can only access elements that exist in the vector. Thats a different `operator[]`.

Count will not give you an iterator to the element if it exists. If you want use the element whether it was present or not, you can use `find` (and `insert` if necessary):

```
auto it = dict.find(i);
if ( it == dict.end() ) {
   it = dict.insert( { i, new Node() } ).first;
}
it->second->val = i;
```

However, don't do this. Store `Node`s in the map instead of pointers. If you need pointers use smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, but not simple.

So to be sure the pointer points to something you need to make a pointer class that if default constructed instantiate a node.

```
template <typename Node>
class IAmNotNull : public std::unique_ptr<Node> { // just inherit unique_ptr because I'm lazy.
public:
   using std::unique_ptr<Node>::unique_ptr<Node>; // use base ctor

   IAmNotNull() :: std::unique_ptr(new Node) { // call base ctor.
   } // overrides base default ctor
}
```

All bugs are your own if you try to use this.